# Result looses conditions on it's has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

## Goal

I have a `project` and a `project` has many `activity` items associated with it.
For the next feature I would like to select a given `Project` with it's `activities` but only those `activities` that are within a given date range.

## Models

> > I already am including the `Invoice` model because I also want to include `Invoice` instances in the next iteration of my code.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities
  has_many :invoices
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :invoice
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

## Fetch @project

This is how I load a given `project` by `id`:

```
@project = Project.includes(:activities).where( activities: { done_at: params[:from]..params[:to] } ).references(:activities).friendly.find( params[:id] )
```

The generated SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT "projects"."id" AS t0_r0, "projects"."title" AS t0_r1, "projects"."description" AS t0_r2, "projects"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "projects"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "projects"."slug" AS t0_r5, "activities"."id" AS t1_r0, "activities"."title" AS t1_r1, "activities"."body" AS t1_r2, "activities"."hours" AS t1_r3, "activities"."done_at" AS t1_r4, "activities"."project_id" AS t1_r5, "activities"."created_at" AS t1_r6, "activities"."updated_at" AS t1_r7, "activities"."invoice_id" AS t1_r8, "activities"."service" AS t1_r9 FROM "projects" LEFT OUTER JOIN "activities" ON "activities"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE ("activities"."done_at" BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND '2014-08-31') AND "projects"."slug" = 'my-website' AND "projects"."id" IN (1)  ORDER BY "projects"."id" ASC
```

The resulting `Project` instance looks like this:

```
#<Project id: 1, title: "My Website", description: "HTML Templates for their new website", created_at: "2014-09-24 07:35:39", updated_at: "2014-09-25 07:10:19", slug: "my-website">
```

## Problem

When I iterate over the resulting `@project` I see **all** its related `activities`.  Not the ones that fall within the given date range.  So in stead of 41 related `activities` as expected, I see all 200+ `activities`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try by changing this query `@project = Project.includes(:activities).where( activities: { done_at: params[:from]..params[:to] } ).references(:activities).friendly.find( params[:id] )` to `@project = Project.includes(:activities).references(:activities).friendly.find( params[:id] ).where( activities: { done_at: params[:from]..params[:to] } )`

Comment: Results in `undefined method `where' for #<Project>`

Comment: @anusha you can't use where after find as find returns the object or ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound. find must be the last call in a chain, and the other methods in the chain need to return a ActiveRecord::Relation.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out one should use `size` to count the number of items in a collection.  If you use `count` Rails will hit the database again.  * *dough* *